Fetch list of addresses of token holders
I'm working on a project involving Solana's SPL tokens and need to retrieve a list of all addresses holding a specific SPL token using JavaScript. However, I'm struggling with getting a list of token holders. How can I do it?

const { Connection, PublicKey } = require('@solana/web3.js');
const { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } = require('@solana/spl-token');

const connection = new Connection('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com');

async function getTokenHolders(tokenMintAddress) {
  const tokenMintPubkey = new PublicKey(tokenMintAddress);

  // Get all token accounts for the given token mint
  const tokenAccounts = await connection.getParsedProgramAccounts(
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // The program ID of the SPL Token program
    {
      filters: [
        {
          dataSize: 165, // Number of bytes for a token account
        },
        {
          memcmp: {
            offset: 0, // Offset to start reading the token mint address
            bytes: tokenMintPubkey.toBase58(), // The token mint address
          },
        },
      ],
    }
  );

  // Filter out accounts with a balance of 0
  const holders = tokenAccounts
    .filter((account) => account.account.data.parsed.info.tokenAmount.uiAmount > 0)
    .map((account) => account.pubkey.toBase58());

  return holders;
}

// Replace with your SPL token mint address
const tokenMintAddress = 'YourTokenMintAddressHere';

getTokenHolders(tokenMintAddress)
  .then((holders) => {
    console.log('Token Holders:', holders);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error fetching token holders:', err);
  });


Connection is used to establish a connection to the Solana cluster.
PublicKey is used to handle Solana public keys.
getParsedProgramAccounts fetches token accounts associated with the given token mint.
Filters are used to ensure we only retrieve SPL token accounts and those associated with the specified mint address.

The result is filtered to exclude accounts with a zero balance.
Replace YourTokenMintAddressHere with the actual SPL token mint address you are interested in. This script will output a list of addresses holding the specified SPL token.
